# How to use VBA to format cells based on value of ANY of the specified cells?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, target

New to VBA here. I'm trying to consolidate code and avoid copy/pasting a million times. Basically if specific cells (but not adjacent: eg, not in a column or range) are blank, then the cells are color filled with a color border. When data is entered into any cell, that particular cell removes any formatting. If the cell is blanked out, the formatting returns. The cells are all independent of each other; just formatting the cell being altered.

Here is a sample from my redundant code, which works, but can there be a way to write it once and just identify the target cells in bulk, so to speak? Put "H154" and "H151" etc on one line?

Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "H154" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        Else: Target.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 43
    End If
 End If

  If Target.Address(False, False) = "H151" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        Else: Target.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
         Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
         Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 43
    End If
 End If

If Target.Address(False, False) = "E3" Then
If Target.Value <> "" Then
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
Target.Borders.ColorIndex = xlNone
Else: Target.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 43
     End If
  End If

     If Target.Address(False, False) = "E9" Then
If Target.Value <> "" Then
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
Target.Borders.ColorIndex = xlNone
Else: Target.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 43
     End If
  End If
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use conditional formatting for this?

Comment: `Select Case` perhaps - `Select Case Target.Address`, `Case "$H$151", $H$154` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, blnk As Boolean

    'any changed cells in the range of interest?
    'adjust range to suit...
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, _
              Me.Range("H154,H151,E3,E9"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'check each changed cell
        For Each c In rng
            blnk = (Len(c.Value) = 0) 'is it empty ?
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(blnk, 43, xlNone)
            c.Borders.LineStyle = IIf(blnk, xlContinuous, xlLineStyleNone)
            If blnk Then c.Borders.ColorIndex = 43
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. I had been trying everything!